# Dynamic big data insert to textarea crushes Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, memory-management

My problem is that chrome crushes when I duplicate many lines in textarea. Code:

```
 $("#duplicate").click(function(){
       var lines = $("#input").val().split("\n");
       $("#input").val("");
       console.log(lines.length, $("#duplicate_num").val());
       for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
           for(var j = 0; j < parseInt($("#duplicate_num").val()); j++){
               $("#input").val($("#input").val()+lines[i]+"\n");
           }
       }
    });
```

Works great with small amounts of data, but as soon as I had to duplicate 500 lines 60 times Chrome died.
Which improvement should I do to keep chrome alive?

Comment: You accessing the DOM way to much. Create the string content for the textarea and update it once at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much good reason to duplicate 500 lines 60 times in any browser, chrome or otherwise. This type of operation is going to be resource intensive no matter how you write it which is why you should really think about what you are trying to accomplish and see if you can work it another way. That said, this should improve performance.

```
 $("#duplicate").click(function(){
       var lines = $("#input").val().split("\n");
       var txt = "";
       var count = parseInt($("#duplicate_num").val());
       var line;
       console.log(lines.length, $("#duplicate_num").val());
       for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
           line = lines[i] + "\n";
           for(var j = 0; j < count; j++){
              txt += line;
           }
       }
       $('#input').val(txt);
    });
```